# Django - extending LogEntry

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the requirement that whenever there is a model get's added/changed/deleted, it should send a mail notification. The content will be more like the django_admin_log entries. I just need to extend this functionality in my model to send the mail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django_log_admin will only track changes made in the admin interface. If the model is changed anywhere else, it will not update the log. However, if you are OK with just admin changes, then you can use a combination of django_log_admin and the post_save signal to do the trick. Put this in your management.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.core.mail import mail_admins
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

#will be triggered every time a LogEntry is saved i.e. every time an action is made.
@receiver(post_save, sender=LogEntry)
def send_notification_email(change, **kwargs):
    mail_admins(subject="model %(model) has been changed by %(user)" % 
                            {'model':change.content_type, 'user': change.user},
                message = render_to_string('change_email.html', { 'change': change }) )
```

note to self: wow, django really includes all the batteries :D

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I required. Since I am using Django 1.2.3, I just removed @receiver and added the following post_save.connect(send_notification_email, sender=LogEntry). But this code never gets called. Do I need to register this to my model somewhere?

Comment: the code should be added anywhere that is automatically imported by django, such as management.py however it could even go in models.py if you're stuck. put a print statement after the imports and see if your management.py is being loaded.

Comment: EDIT: django docs say to create a folder called management in your app and put this in __init__.py within that folder.

Comment: P.S. @reciever is perfectly valid in Django 1.2.3. see: [signals#connecting-receiver-functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions). Also, i think it is much cleaner looking, but that's just me :D

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Django's [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).  In your case, you'll connect your handlers to the `post_save` and `post_delete` signals, for starters.  Look through the [built-in signal documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) for others you may want to tap.  No need to hack into `admin`.

Comment: The problem here is that we will not have the user details like currently logged username in these signal.

Comment: Hm, yes, that seems to be the case.  Makes sense, too; not every object action is user-initiated.  Do you need to record those actions as well?

Comment: Yeah. Thats why I just want to extend the LogEntry class. It will have all the details I required.

Comment: LogEntry won't catch changes not made via admin.

Comment: Okay. I am not sure which method inserts 'django_admin_log' table? Is it possible to extend that method to send email?